# Delete entire mysql row by grabbing link?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I have a list of users with names and emails displayed for admins and users ON THE SAME PAGE....

If an admin views it it shows an extra column called "Action"

Which shows three links

```
Edit | Delete | Make Admin

--------------------------
```

I have the delete button grab information from that table row and move it into a link

Here is the setup

```
echo "
<td>
  <a href='admin.php?action=deleteuser&username={$row['username']}'>Delete</a>
</td>";
```

Here it is in action:
    admin.php?action=deleteuser&username=bob

I spaced it out for viewing purposes.....

Anyways

I want the site to somehow grab the information FROM the url and somehow delete the row where username is equal to "bob" or something like that

Any ways to do this? Please help out.

Also how would I make it secure since the page is accessible to anyone so if someone was to manually type that link they would delete it wouldn't they?

Maybe check if the user is admin before the link runs

Here is my check admin code

```
if (has_access($session_user_id, 1) === true) {
    echo 'The user is an admin!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in admin.php ?

```
function getLoginUserByCookie()
{
  return isset($_COOKIE["loginusername"]) ? $_COOKIE["loginusername"] : "";
}

if(getLoginUserByCookie() != "admin")
{
  header("Location: /login.php");
  exit;
}

try {
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase", "dbuser", "dbpass");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$strSQL = "DELETE FROM users WHERE (username=:username);";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($strSQL);
$stmt->execute(array(
  ":username" => $_GET["username"]
));
```

/login.php is a big job, you might find some example to check login. And save loginusername in cookie.